Rich Results Test URL crawled successfully but no Items detected
I pasted a URL to the Rich Results test, and it was successfully crawled but returns No Items Detected.
If I copied the html content and pasted that in it shows the JobPosting correctly.
Example web page

As you can see in this picture json-ld script is visible but when I paste the URL in Rich Results Test it shows as no items detected. If I copy and paste the Html element it shows as valid item detected.

Two things to try out:

Structured data should be an object, not an array
Place the structured data in head, not in body


Thank you for your response. I set it like you said now it works.
